# anyone who has used Atlassian's Elastic Bamboo to build .NET projects - what AMI do I need to use?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, nant

This whole setup process is fairly perplexing, and I feel like the documentation is written for CI and cloud experts. Can anybody lend some inght into their setup?

Answer (score 2):

I've detailed how to set up your own AMI to use at :
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/gracemollison/archive/2011/01/18/how-to-set-up-a-windows-ami-to-use-with-elastic-bamboo.aspx